# How to handle multiple atlas files

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, texture-atlas

I have a bunch of images in a folder name myImages.atlas. These images when put together will take up more than 2048x2048. Based on the Apple documentation I would have expected XCode to automatically break this up into multiple files.

```
After an image has reached its maximum size, a new image is created.
```

But when I try to compile it fails with the error:

```
sprikekit texture atlas generator error cannot fit input texture into a maximum supported dimensions of 2048 x 2048
```

Does anyone know if it's possible for XCode to handle this sceanrio and if yes what might I be doing wrong?

Comment: what is the biggest image you are trying to put in that atlas ?

Comment: @whirlwind At the moment 2048x1536. These are just place holders tho, In the final version this will be much smaller, but all images combined will still take up more than 2048x2048.

Comment: Yeah, I've just tried...Weird ... Also, I had success with textures of size 2035x1536... It looks like you can't go up to 2048px.